# Pop elements divisible by 3 and 7 from the list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to pop elements divisible by 3 and 7 from the list. This is the code I wrote, but it's not working properly.

```
tab = []

for i in range(20):
    tab.append(int(input("Input number: ")))

for i in tab: 
    if (i % 3 != 0) and (i % 7 != 0):
        continue
    else: 
        tab.pop(i)

print(tab)
```

Comment: Don't remove from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: `tab = [i for i in range(20) if (i % 3 != 0) and (i % 7 != 0)]`

Comment: "divisible by 3 and 7" is a complicated way of saying "divisible by 21". Is that what you meant, or did you mean something different?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working"